# Creating an iOS8 Framework dependent on external library

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, afnetworking-2, ios-frameworks

I am creating an iOS8 Cocoa Touch Framework that is internally dependent on AFNetworking. I don't want to compile AFNetworking into my framework and let the user of the framework provide AFNetworking. I am unable to find any guide on the right way to do this with or without CocoaPods, any thoughts ?

The reason I don't want to compile AFNetworking into my framework is:
1. To keep framework size minimal
2. Avoid any conflict with existing code of a developer who uses my framework e.g. if user is already using AFNetworking and just now decides to import my framework

Comment: Doesn't Cocoapods handle these conflicts already? http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: @MikeD I'm just talking about conflicts in general doesn't matter how the other user decides to use the other framework: using or not using CocoaPods

Comment: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#how-do-i-include-third-party-libraries-in-my-framework

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling "YOUR" framework which uses "OTHER" framework, the people who consume "YOUR" framework should also include "OTHER" framework in their project.

But for you to compile you project anyway you have to include "OTHER" framework in your project. So, as far as i know, you can not exclude the "OTHER" framework from your project. Hope it helps.

Comment: That is the thing, I am searching to exclude the "OTHER" framework from "MY" framework

Comment: As far as i know you can not do that, technically how can you compile without adding the "OTHER" framework. You can not call "OTHER" framework methods with out adding it.

Comment: isn't that the difference between compiling and linking? "MY" and "OTHER" could compile separately and then linked up

Comment: "OTHER" framework is already compiled and you do not compile it again in your project, all you do is link it in your project when you use methods from "OTHER" framework. So, you have to link "OTHER" framework to compile "YOUR" framework.

Comment: this is what I was looking for: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#how-do-i-include-third-party-libraries-in-my-framework

Comment: I do not think it is possible, technically. Let me know if you find any thing for this. I also need this hack ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76092/discussion-between-2cupsoftech-and-ikrish).

Comment: Did you find anything on this?